# Get text of clicked button in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to be able to know exactly which element from a class has been clicked. I enabled the `text` option in Tag Manager:

[image]

But it's still not visible in the click object. But it wouldn't pick it up, since the tag containing the text is nested in the clickable element. Can I add a custom HTML attribute to be able to identify which element has been clicked?

```
<div class="card-content"> //<---- clickable element
  <i aria-hidden="true" class="card-icon material-icons">business</i>
  <h3 class="card-title">Company details</h3> //<--- clicked text
</div>
```

[image: Google Analytics click object]

Comment: Do I understand well, that you would like to know, whether the icon or the h3 element has been clicked?

Comment: Once `.card-content` has been clicked, I'd like to see the text of the nested `<h3>`. If impossible, then I'd like to be able to add a custom HTML attribute to `.card-content` in order to be able to identify it

Answer (score 0):

The best way to figure it out is to use the "Preview & Debug":

- Activate it
- Go to the page where you want to test (you should see now a new box at the bottom)
- Click on the element
- Check the variables in the debug box. Especially check the click.element data.

My guess is that since there is no "real" text in the div box, just children tags, no text can be discovered.

There are different options to solve it:

- add the text as data-attribute to the div and use the click.element data
- use a data-layer push event
- if you know JS you can use the click.element data in a JS variable and traverse down to the h3

Comment: If I add a `data-attribute` it doesn't pick it up, it's not in the `click` object, how do I tell GTM to look for it? I cannot add custom attributes under `configure`

Comment: data-attribute will not be picked up automatically. But you could try create to create a data layer variable using "gtm.element.dataset.xyz". See more about the click.element here: https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/click-element-variable-in-google-tag-manager/

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to keep your code as it is, you could create a custom variable, using Custom JavaScript.

In order to do so you need to first create the custom variable, choosing the Custom JavaScript type:

[image]

This code should do the job (I tested id)

```
function() {
    return {{Click Element}}.closest('.card-content').getElementsByClassName('card-title')[0].innerText;    
}
```

[image]

The custom variable will return the text inside .card-title.

To test the custom variable, you may create a dumb HTML tag with a `console.log` script, replacing `Inside TXT` with the name you gave to your custom variable:

```
<script>console.log( {{Inside TXT}} )</script>
```

[image]

The trigger should be a Click All Elements.

[image]

When previewing this tag, the captured text should appear in your console, as well as in the debugger panel.

Reading again your question, I wonder if you are going to have several .card-title items inside the .card-content. In that case, this custom variable will not work. Let me know what is the case.

Also, the code could be simpler, but I am not really sure on how is it really going to work in your site, so this one seems more reliable, since it works clicking anywhere in the element.

**EDIT:**
In order to test it, after you click an element, a new "Click" will appear in the left pane (Summary). There, in the Variables tab, you will see the variables captured by the click. The data will be stored under the variable name you gave to the variable.

[image]

Comment: I created the variable with a custom JS function, it's still not showing up under "variables" or "data layer" in the preview mode window, however. I have many `.card-content` elements inline

Comment: It would be useful to know how or where you want to send this captured data. Just to check how you are using the debugger, after click an element, a new "Click" will appear in the left pane (Summary). There, in the Variables tab, you will see the variables captured by the click. The data will be stored under the variable name you gave to the variable.

Comment: When I add it in the dashboard, it doesn't show up on that underbar under `Variables` or `data layer` like it does for you

Comment: There are a couple of things to check. Did you create a trigger and a tag in order to test this Custom Variable? You need a Click All Elements trigger before you can see it in the debugger. If you already did so, do you see the clicks in the left pane whenever you click?

Comment: I have "all clicks", "all elements", "form submission" and "just links" triggers. Are some of these mutually exclusive? I have an underpane (same as the one above) where I get to see my click objects with their data layer and checkbox variables, but not the custom ones

Comment: Do you see the tag fired when you click. Before clicking it should show as "Tags Not Fired" and after a click in any element (if you are using All Elements) it should be in the Tags Fired section. I will add also some editions to my original post to see if it helps you.

Comment: Could you share the URL or the whole HTML code of the page?

Comment: When I add the custom HTML tag, it tells me "Unless a trigger is added, the tag will not fire". Following a click, under "Tags fired" I get "Google Analytics App + Web Configuration". Page's rendered HTML: https://codepen.io/tdimoff/pen/NWxKMZE